# Hyperledger fabric custom policy during channel creation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have an error during a policy evaluation. The above policy is a custom policy that I defined in my `configtx.yml`
Here a snippet of it where my system channel profile and my application channel profile are defined (I'm including only relevant parts).

```
 Organizations:
  - &Org
   Name:  MyOrg
   ID:  MyOrg
   MSPDir: crypto-config/organizations/org.com/msp
   Policies: &OrgPolicy
    System:
     Type: Signature
     Rule: "OR(' MyOrg.admin')"

    Readers:
     Type: Signature
     Rule: "OR(' MyOrg.member')"
    Writers:
     Type: Signature
     Rule: "OR(' MyOrg.member')"
    Admins:
     Type: Signature
     Rule: "OR(' MyOrg.admin')"

   AnchorPeers:
    - Host: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 7051

 Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  ACLs: &ACLsDefault
   qscc/GetBlockByNumber: /Channel/Application/Admins

  Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
   System: 
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY System" 
   Readers:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Readers"
   Writers:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "MAJORITY Writers"
   Admins:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

 Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  ....
  Policies:
   System: 
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Admins"
   Readers:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Readers"
   Writers:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Writers"
   Admins:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ALL Admins"
   BlockValidation:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Writers"Policies:
   System: 
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Admins"
   Readers:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Readers"
   Writers:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Writers"
   Admins:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ALL Admins"
   # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
   # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
   BlockValidation:
    Type: ImplicitMeta
    Rule: "ANY Writers"
 ....
 Profiles:
  ApplicationChannel:
   Consortium: MyOrgConsortium
   <<: *ChannelDefaults
   Application:
    <<: *ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    - *MyOrg
    Capabilities:
     <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

  MyOrgSysChannelConfiguration:
   <<: *ChannelDefaults
   Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
   Orderer:
    <<: *OrdererDefaults
    Organizations:
    - *MyOrg
    Capabilities:
     <<: *OrdererCapabilities
   Application:
    <<: *ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    - <<: *MyOrg
   Consortiums:
    MyOrgConsortium:
     Organizations:
     - *MyOrg
```

I'm than generating my artifacts:

```sh
 bin/configtxgen -profile MyOrgSysChannelConfiguration -channelID sys-channel -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block

 bin/configtxgen -profile ApplicationChannel -outputCreateChannelTx ./channel-artifacts/blockchain.tx -channelID application-channel
```

I can then inspect my genesis block and here the relevant parts of the `bin/configtxgen -inspectBlock` output:

```
 {
  "data": {
   "data": [
    {
     "payload": {
      "data": {
       "config": {
        "channel_group": {
         "groups": {
          "Application": {
           "groups": {
            "MyOrg": {
             "groups": {},
             "policies": {
              "Admins": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "ADMIN"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              },
              "Readers": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "MEMBER"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              },
              "System": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "ADMIN"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              },
              "Writers": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "MEMBER"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              }
             },
             "values": {
              ....
             },
            }
           },
           "policies": {
            "Admins": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "MAJORITY",
               "sub_policy": "Admins"
              }
             },
            },
            "Readers": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "ANY",
               "sub_policy": "Readers"
              }
             },
            },
            "System": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "ANY",
               "sub_policy": "System"
              }
             },
            },
            "Writers": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "MAJORITY",
               "sub_policy": "Writers"
              }
             },
            }
           },
           "values": {
            "ACLs": {
             "value": {
              "acls": {
               "qscc/GetBlockByNumber": {
                "policy_ref": "/Channel/Application/System"
               },
              }
             },
            },
            "Capabilities": {
             ...
            }
           },
          },
          "Consortiums": {
           "groups": {
            "MyOrgConsortium": {
             "groups": {
              "MyOrg": {
               "groups": {},
               "policies": {
                "Admins": {
                 "policy": {
                  "type": 1,
                  "value": {
                   "identities": [
                    {
                     "principal": {
                      "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                      "role": "ADMIN"
                     },
                     "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                    }
                   ],
                   "rule": {
                    "n_out_of": {
                     "n": 1,
                     "rules": [
                      {
                       "signed_by": 0
                      }
                     ]
                    }
                   },
                   "version": 0
                  }
                 },
                },
                "Readers": {
                 "policy": {
                  "type": 1,
                  "value": {
                   "identities": [
                    {
                     "principal": {
                      "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                      "role": "MEMBER"
                     },
                     "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                    }
                   ],
                   "rule": {
                    "n_out_of": {
                     "n": 1,
                     "rules": [
                      {
                       "signed_by": 0
                      }
                     ]
                    }
                   },
                   "version": 0
                  }
                 },
                },
                "System": {
                 "policy": {
                  "type": 1,
                  "value": {
                   "identities": [
                    {
                     "principal": {
                      "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                      "role": "ADMIN"
                     },
                     "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                    }
                   ],
                   "rule": {
                    "n_out_of": {
                     "n": 1,
                     "rules": [
                      {
                       "signed_by": 0
                      }
                     ]
                    }
                   },
                   "version": 0
                  }
                 },
                },
                "Writers": {
                 "policy": {
                  "type": 1,
                  "value": {
                   "identities": [
                    {
                     "principal": {
                      "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                      "role": "MEMBER"
                     },
                     "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                    }
                   ],
                   "rule": {
                    "n_out_of": {
                     "n": 1,
                     "rules": [
                      {
                       "signed_by": 0
                      }
                     ]
                    }
                   },
                   "version": 0
                  }
                 },
                }
               },
               "values": {
                ....
               },
              }
             },
             ....
            }
           },
           "mod_policy": "/Channel/Orderer/Admins",
           "policies": {
            "Admins": {
             "mod_policy": "/Channel/Orderer/Admins",
             "policy": {
              "type": 1,
              "value": {
               "identities": [],
               "rule": {
                "n_out_of": {
                 "n": 0,
                 "rules": []
                }
               },
               "version": 0
              }
             },
            }
           },
           "values": {},
          },
          "Orderer": {
           "groups": {
            "MyOrg": {
             "groups": {},
             "policies": {
              "Admins": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "ADMIN"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              },
              "Readers": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "MEMBER"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              },
              "System": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "ADMIN"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              },
              "Writers": {
               "policy": {
                "type": 1,
                "value": {
                 "identities": [
                  {
                   "principal": {
                    "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                    "role": "MEMBER"
                   },
                   "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                  }
                 ],
                 "rule": {
                  "n_out_of": {
                   "n": 1,
                   "rules": [
                    {
                     "signed_by": 0
                    }
                   ]
                  }
                 },
                 "version": 0
                }
               },
              }
             },
             "values": {
              ...
             },
            }
           },
           "policies": {
            "Admins": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "ALL",
               "sub_policy": "Admins"
              }
             },
            },
            "BlockValidation": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "ANY",
               "sub_policy": "Writers"
              }
             },
            },
            "Readers": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "ANY",
               "sub_policy": "Readers"
              }
             },
            },
            "System": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "ANY",
               "sub_policy": "Admins"
              }
             },
            },
            "Writers": {
             "policy": {
              "type": 3,
              "value": {
               "rule": "ANY",
               "sub_policy": "Writers"
              }
             },
            }
           },
           "values": {
            "BatchSize": {
             "value": {
              "absolute_max_bytes": 10485760,
              "max_message_count": 500,
              "preferred_max_bytes": 2097152
             },
            },
            "BatchTimeout": {
             "value": {
              "timeout": "2s"
             },
            },
            "Capabilities": {
             "value": {
              "capabilities": {
               "V1_4_2": {}
              }
             },
            },
            "ChannelRestrictions": {
             "value": null,
            },
            "ConsensusType": {
             ...
            }
           },
          }
         },
         "policies": {
          ...
         },
         "values": {
          ...
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
```

As expected I can see that my custom policy System, which I use to control access list over the get block by number resource, is included at all level I defined it.
What you wanna notice is that it is defined under the Application group where `MyOrg.policy`.

So I'm ready to deploy my System channel and run submit the create channel transaction previously generated from my `configtx.yml`.

So far so good!

I'm now fetching the last version of the configuration for my `application-channel` which is the following omitting not relevant parts:

```
{
    "data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "payload": {
                    "data": {
                        "config": {
                            "channel_group": {
                                "groups": {
                                    "Application": {
                                        "groups": {
                                            "MyOrg": {
                                                "groups": {},
                                                "policies": {
                                                    "Admins": {
                                                        "policy": {
                                                            "type": 1,
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "identities": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "principal": {
                                                                            "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                                                                            "role": "ADMIN"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "rule": {
                                                                    "n_out_of": {
                                                                        "n": 1,
                                                                        "rules": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "signed_by": 0
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "version": 0
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                    "Readers": {
                                                        "policy": {
                                                            "type": 1,
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "identities": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "principal": {
                                                                            "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                                                                            "role": "MEMBER"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "rule": {
                                                                    "n_out_of": {
                                                                        "n": 1,
                                                                        "rules": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "signed_by": 0
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "version": 0
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                    "Writers": {
                                                        "policy": {
                                                            "type": 1,
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "identities": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "principal": {
                                                                            "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                                                                            "role": "MEMBER"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "rule": {
                                                                    "n_out_of": {
                                                                        "n": 1,
                                                                        "rules": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "signed_by": 0
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "version": 0
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    }
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE! HERE! IT IS MISSING HERE! >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                                                },
                                                "values": {
                                                    ...
                                                },
                                                "version": "1"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "policies": {
                                            "Admins": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "MAJORITY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Admins"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            },
                                            "Readers": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "ANY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Readers"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            },
                                            "System": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "ANY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "System"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            },
                                            "Writers": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "MAJORITY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Writers"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "values": {
                                            "ACLs": {
                                            ...
                                        },
                                        "version": "1"
                                    },
                                    "Orderer": {
                                        "groups": {
                                            "MyOrg": {
                                                "groups": {},
                                                "policies": {
                                                    "Admins": {
                                                        "policy": {
                                                            "type": 1,
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "identities": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "principal": {
                                                                            "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                                                                            "role": "ADMIN"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "rule": {
                                                                    "n_out_of": {
                                                                        "n": 1,
                                                                        "rules": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "signed_by": 0
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "version": 0
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                    "Readers": {
                                                        "policy": {
                                                            "type": 1,
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "identities": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "principal": {
                                                                            "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                                                                            "role": "MEMBER"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "rule": {
                                                                    "n_out_of": {
                                                                        "n": 1,
                                                                        "rules": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "signed_by": 0
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "version": 0
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                    "System": {
                                                        "policy": {
                                                            "type": 1,
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "identities": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "principal": {
                                                                            "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                                                                            "role": "ADMIN"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "rule": {
                                                                    "n_out_of": {
                                                                        "n": 1,
                                                                        "rules": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "signed_by": 0
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "version": 0
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                    "Writers": {
                                                        "policy": {
                                                            "type": 1,
                                                            "value": {
                                                                "identities": [
                                                                    {
                                                                        "principal": {
                                                                            "msp_identifier": "MyOrg",
                                                                            "role": "MEMBER"
                                                                        },
                                                                        "principal_classification": "ROLE"
                                                                    }
                                                                ],
                                                                "rule": {
                                                                    "n_out_of": {
                                                                        "n": 1,
                                                                        "rules": [
                                                                            {
                                                                                "signed_by": 0
                                                                            }
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                },
                                                                "version": 0
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "values": {
                                                ....
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "policies": {
                                            "Admins": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "ALL",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Admins"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            },
                                            "BlockValidation": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "ANY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Writers"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            },
                                            "Readers": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "ANY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Readers"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            },
                                            "System": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "ANY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Admins"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            },
                                            "Writers": {
                                                "policy": {
                                                    "type": 3,
                                                    "value": {
                                                        "rule": "ANY",
                                                        "sub_policy": "Writers"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "values": {
                                            ...
                                        },
                                    }
                                },
                                "policies": {
                                    "Admins": {
                                        "policy": {
                                            "type": 3,
                                            "value": {
                                                "rule": "ALL",
                                                "sub_policy": "Admins"
                                            }
                                        },
                                    },
                                    "Readers": {
                                        "policy": {
                                            "type": 3,
                                            "value": {
                                                "rule": "ANY",
                                                "sub_policy": "Readers"
                                            }
                                        },
                                    },
                                    "Writers": {
                                        "policy": {
                                            "type": 3,
                                            "value": {
                                                "rule": "ANY",
                                                "sub_policy": "Writers"
                                            }
                                        },
                                    }
                                },
                                "values": {
                                    ...
                                },
                            },
                            "sequence": "2"
                        },
                        "last_update": {
                            "payload": {
                                "data": {
                                    "config_update": {
                                        "channel_id": "application-channel",
                                        "isolated_data": {},
                                        "read_set": {
                                            "groups": {
                                                "Application": {
                                                    "groups": {
                                                        "MyOrg": {
                                                            "groups": {},
                                                            "mod_policy": "",
                                                            "policies": {
                                                                "Admins": {
                                                                    "mod_policy": "",
                                                                    "policy": null,
                                                                },
                                                                "Readers": {
                                                                    "mod_policy": "",
                                                                    "policy": null,
                                                                },
                                                                "Writers": {
                                                                    "mod_policy": "",
                                                                    "policy": null,
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "values": {
                                                                "MSP": {
                                                                    "mod_policy": "",
                                                                    "value": null,
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "policies": {},
                                                    "values": {},
                                                    "version": "1"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "mod_policy": "",
                                            "policies": {},
                                            "values": {},
                                        },
                                        "write_set": {
                                            "groups": {
                                                "Application": {
                                                    "groups": {
                                                        "MyOrg": {
                                                            "groups": {},
                                                            "policies": {
                                                                "Admins": {
                                                                    "mod_policy": "",
                                                                    "policy": null,
                                                                },
                                                                "Readers": {
                                                                    "mod_policy": "",
                                                                    "policy": null,
                                                                },
                                                                "Writers": {
                                                                    "mod_policy": "",
                                                                    "policy": null,
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "values": {
                                                            ...
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "policies": {},
                                                    "values": {},
                                                    "version": "1"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "mod_policy": "",
                                            "policies": {},
                                            "values": {},
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "signatures": [
                                        ...
                                    ]
                                },
                                "header": {
                                    ...
                                }
                            },

                        }
                    },
                    "header": {
                        ...
                    }
                },

            }
        ]
    },
    "header": {
        ...
    },
    "metadata": {
        ....
    }
}
```

This does not make sense to me.. Yuo can notice that at `Application.group.MyOrg.policy` my custom policy is not defined. However it is defined in all the other level where MyOrg has been included in the channel definition in the `confitx.yml` file.
The fact that the type signature policy is not defined at `Application` level produce the effect of not being possible to endorse the `GetBlockByNumber` since it evaluated firstly as implicit meta policy that can't be resolved in a signature policy.

Am I doing something wrong in the application channel definition?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Everything here looks like it should be working, if I had to guess, I would say that the orderer system channel was bootstrapped with an older iteration of `configtx.yaml`.  Defining additional policies beyond Readers/Writers/Admin and having them inherited in channel creation has been tested (and in fact, you'll see some new policies appear by default related to the new lifecycle in v2.0).  Let me provide a little bit more context to help you track things down.

When you bootstrap your orderers with a genesis block, this block is the start of the orderer system channel.  The orderer system channel is used to coordinate channel creation events across orderers.

When a channel creation transaction is received (which is actually just a special sort of configuration update transaction) the orderer generates an ephemeral configuration based on the current contents of the orderer system channel. 
 It takes the top level, channel group, the orderer group, and the organizations defined in the consortium definition, to create a sort of template configuration.  This template configuration includes the organization definitions *as defined in the orderer system channel consortium definition*.

Meanwhile, when you generate a channel configuration transaction with `configtxgen`, by default, only the policies, ACLs, and capabilities in the 'Application' section are honored.  The other sections, including the Channel level items (such as capabilities and policies), the Orderer level items (such as policies, ordering orgs, consensus config), and all of the Application Org contents are ignored.  The only exception is the name of the organizations to include in the channel.  So, when you inspect the channel creation transaction, you'll note that none of your organization information, such as CAs, and policies, are included in the output.

So, even though your `configtx.yaml` references an org with custom policies defined in it, `configtxgen` assumes that those policies are already present in the orderer system channel and does nothing.  Note: This behavior is a 'feature' rather than a bug, because when creating a channel with many organizations, the creator wants the latest CAs, CRLs, policies etc. as defined by the org owner, rather than having to gather all of those artifacts manually.

Based on the information you provided above, it looks to me like your custom policy definitions should be in your consortium definition on the orderer system channel, and that they should be inherited in the template configuration of your new channel.  However, since this is not occurring, my only conclusion is that the organizations in the orderer system channel consortium definition do not in fact have these supplementary policies.  You can confirm this by pulling the latest config block of the orderer system channel via `peer channel fetch config` and decoding.